# Draw scatter plot using d3

Tags: javascript, html, graph, svg, d3.js

So what I am trying to do is build some sort of a chart with bars and line cross this bar

The horizontal line represent an average number of whatever, and the bars of course represent individual values.

For each bar of this when it exceeds the average it should be green, if not it should be red.

So what I reached is make the colour of the bars change depending on the value - easy :)
Draw a line and control its height as I want, so it represents the value of the average - also not that difficult

But here is the problem when I put both of them together that bars are shown fine, but I can't see the line. Although when you right click and inspect element you will find that it is there but not visible.

here is my code

```
<html>

<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-2.0.3.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-2.3.0.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-2.3.0.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-2.3.0.js'></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="sticky-footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<style type="text/css">

        div.bar {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 20px;
            height: 75px;
            margin-right:2%;
        }

        #svg{
            margin-top:5%;
            margin-left:5%; 
        }

    </style>

 </head>

 <body>

    <div id="svg"></div>

    <script>
    var dataset = [8,17,25];       
    var avg = 16.6666666;
    var w = 600;
    var h = 300;
    var barPadding = 45;
    console.log(dataset);

    var svg = d3.select("#svg")
                .attr("width", w)  
                .attr("height", h);;

    svg.selectAll("div")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .style("height", function(d) {
            return d*5 + "px";
        })
        .style("background-color",function(d,i){ console.log("D| " + d);    if(d>avg) return "green"; else { return "red"; } });


        var line = svg.append("line")
                      .attr("x1", 5)
                      .attr("y1", 5)
                      .attr("x2", 50)
                      .attr("y2", 5)
                      .attr("stroke-width", 10)
                      .attr("stroke", "black"); 

</script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you can't see the line is that there is no `line` HTML element. It looks like you're trying to combine code from examples that use HTML and SVG to render the graph. This will not work, you need to decide on one of those and use it consistently.

For your purposes, it looks like SVG would be the better choice. You should be able to use it with only minor modifications, i.e. append a SVG element to the `div` and use `rect`s for the bars instead of `div`s. There are plenty of examples for this on the web. You may find [NVD3](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/linePlusBar.html) helpful -- you could use it almost unmodified for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However note that NVD3.js is completely different concept from d3.js, although they do the same job

Comment: NVD3 is basically a set of high-level functions based on D3, so I wouldn't call them completely different.